# What is wrong with my starting values

Tags: r

I am using nleqslv package in R to solve nonlinear system of equations. The R codes are given below;

```
require(nleqslv)

x <- c(6,12,18,24,30)

NMfun1 <- function(k,n) {
     y <- rep(NA, length(k))

     y[1] <- -(5/k[1])+sum(x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x))+2*sum(k[4]*x^k[2]*exp(-k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x)+k[3]*x)/(1-k[4]*exp(-k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x))))

     y[2] <- -sum(log(x))-sum(1/(k[2]+k[3]*x))+sum(k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x)*log(x))+2*sum(k[1]*k[4]*exp(-k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x)+k[3]*x)*log(x)/(1-k[4]*exp(-k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x))))

     y[3] <- -sum(x/(k[2]+k[3]*x))+sum(k[1]*x^(k[2]+1)*exp(k[3]*x))-sum(x)+2*sum(k[4]*x^k[2]*exp(-k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x)+k[3]*x)/(1-k[4]*exp(-k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x))))

     y[4] <- -(5/(1-k[4]))+2*sum(exp(-k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x))/(1-k[4]*exp(-k[1]*x^k[2]*exp(k[3]*x))))

     return(y)

}

kstart <- c(0.05, 0, 0.35, 0.9)

NMfun1(kstart)

nleqslv(kstart, NMfun1, control=list(btol=.0001),method="Newton")
```

The estimated values for k obtained are; `0.04223362 -0.08360564  0.14216026  0.37854908`

But the estimated values of k are to be
 greater than zero.

Comment: If you want to estimate positive integers your problem is your method, not your starting values. (That said, if you want to estimate positive integers, why are you starting at non-integer values?)

Comment: Maybe try the `nloptr` package, it is for non-linear programming problems.

Comment: Package `nleqslv` does not have an option to force integer values solutions. It attempts to find a real valued solution that solves the equation system. How do you know that there is an integer valued solution? You'll have to look elsewhere for a way to solve your problem if it has a solution!

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The estimates values are suppose to be real and greater than zero.It was a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So you want real larger than 0 solutions if they exist of course.
Make a new function which squares the input argument before passing it to `NMfun1`. And then use the `searchZeros` function in the package `nleqslv` to search for solutions. Like this

```
NMfun1.alt <- function(k0,n) NMfun1(k0^2,n)

3 use set.seed for reproducibility
set.seed(413)

# generate 100 random starting values
xstart <- matrix(runif(4*100,min=0,max=1), nrow=100,ncol=4)
z <- searchZeros(xstart,NMfun1.alt)
z
ksol <- z$x^2
ksol

# in this case there are two solutions
NMfun1(ksol[1,])
NMfun1(ksol[2,])
```

The output of the last 4 non comment lines of this code are

```
> ksol <- z$x^2
> ksol
            [,1]     [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,] 0.002951051 1.669142 0.03589502 0.001167185
[2,] 0.002951051 1.669142 0.03589502 0.001167185
> NMfun1(ksol[1,])
[1]  3.231138e-11  3.602561e-13 -4.665268e-12 -1.119105e-13
> NMfun1(ksol[2,])
[1]  1.532663e-12  1.085046e-14  6.894485e-14 -2.664535e-15
```

You will see that the solution contained in object `z` has a negative element. And that is squared.
From this experiment it appears that your system has a single positive solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Bhas. You are the best.

Comment: Bhas,I tried using your method but it didn't work for me.Am I suppose to create a new script for the searchZeros function?How do I like this with NMfun1 script?Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "... it didn't work for me"? The code I gave in my answer should be appended to your original code. `searchZeros` is in package `nleqslv`.